# Is it okay to use .animate with 0 duration all the time? Is there a better alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've grown used to code my jquery animation by doing the following.

1. Set the initial state of the element (things like width, height, top, left, opacity, etc...) using either css or javascript. This initial state is the state at the **end** of the animation.
2. Use .animate with 0 duration to move the element to the state in which elements are at the beginning of the animation.
3. Use a regular .animate with the appropriate duration to do the animation in which at the end, the elements are back to state in step 1.

Here is an example.

```
/* css file */
.animatedObject
{
    width:60%;
}

// javascript file
$('.animatedObject')
    .animate({width: '-=20%'}, 0)
    .animate({width: '+=20%'}, 1000);
```

There are several advantage using this code at least for me. First, it looks clear to me what I'm trying to animate. Second, if javascript is disabled, the object would be at the end state of the animation which is often where I want it to be for graceful degradation. Third, objects can change position slightly for adjustments using css and the animation would still look largely the same.

The reason I'm not using the .css is that it if I try to replace the animate with 0 duration with the .css method, I would get differing animation starting point. I don't think it support += or -=, or if it does, it behaves differently.

So, is this a good way to do this? What is the industry standard way?

Comment: Why do you think it behaves differently?

Comment: Because i wrote some test code to try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could still use `.css()`:

```
var anObj = $('.animatedObject');
anObj.css("width", anObj.css("width") - (20 / anObj.css("width"))).animate({
    width: '+=20%'
}, 1000);
```

I believe this would work faster.

## Edit:

I did a little benchmark for you, using [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com). Here are my results (using `Google Chrome`):

### `.animate({}, 0)`

#### Code:

```
$('.animatedObject')
    .animate({width: '-=20%'}, 0)
    .animate({width: '+=20%'}, 1000);
```

#### End Results:

`10,013 operations per second`
`±7.48%`
`fastest`

### `.css();`

#### Code:

```
var anObj = $('.animatedObject');
anObj.css("width", anObj.css("width") - (20 / anObj.css("width"))).animate({
    width: '+=20%'
}, 1000);
```

#### End Results:

`2,477 operations per second`
`±6.39%`
`75% slower`

### Conclusion

Keep the animation function. It turns out using `.css()` is actually slower. I guess it's the fact that you have 2 extra functions. It's  not worth it. This was actually a surprise to me as I thought `.css()` would function faster than it did. [Test this yourself](http://jsperf.com/animate-0-vs-css) in your browser!

Comment: This might work faster, but my sanity would take a hit. How much faster would it be? One of the reason I'm asking the question is to know what kind of performance .animate with 0 duration would take. If it's not that much compared to using .css, I think I'll keep using .animate for the sake of simplicity.